# How to sum previous month values and current month values in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

Please help me to solve this issue. I have to write a query to get the sum of previous month values and current month values but not able to get the solution.

Here is an image for your reference sum of actual count column values I need the result.

[image]

Comment: Do you want this in Tableau or SQL ? In Tableau we can achieve this easily .

Comment: Please give me the solution in Tableau.

Comment: research `group by rollup`

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you would use the following, could be not completely correct on the case statement:

```
Select 
      Site, 
      sum(value * (case (date_transaction > trunc(sysdate, 'MM') then 1 else 0 end))
        volume_current_month
    from myTable
    where date_transaction between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-1) and sysdate
    group by site
```

The previous month is more or less the same using another case statement and `ADD_MONTHS`.

Comment: It is hard to get the formatting correctly, even with the hints. Sorry.

Comment: Normally that would be `CASE WHEN`, but perhaps Oracle accepts this?

Comment: Thanks for your response i will try.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this in Tableau :

First Way .

```
Under Analysis --> Total --> Add All SubTotals .
```

Second Way :

Create a calc field `Total_event` as :

```
WINDOW_SUM(SUM([Event Count]))
```

Compute the Window_sum as `COMPUTE USING EVENT NAME` .

Comment: i was try this but the result is not expected, Please refer the link - "https://community.tableau.com/", i have requested the issues in tableau please check the question is "How to find the difference from the previous Month in each site"

Comment: i need only the actual count sum or difference from current month and previous month.

Comment: @KannanAthmanathan What result are you getting  ? I am getting the desired result as per your requirement . You might share public link of your problem .

Answer (score 0):

In tableau -> Create a calculated field ->

// This is for previous month

```
if [date] >= DATE("01" +"-" + (Month(TODAY())-1) +"-" + YEAR(TODAY()))

and [date] <= DATE("31" +"-" + (Month(TODAY())-1) +"-" + YEAR(TODAY()))

//if the month has 30 or 28 days it will check that there is no 31 and return null

then

sum([Value])

end
```

//For current month ->

```
if Month([date]) = Month(TODAY()) then

sum([Value])

end
```

You will 2 fields returning previous month's sum and current month's sum, You can then use them as you wish.

On sql end you may use

For Previous Month ->

```
select sum(value) from table_name t where DATE_PART('month',t.date)=DATE_PART('month',TIMESTAMPADD(mm,-1,GETDATE()))
```

For current Month ->

```
select sum(value) from table_name t where DATE_PART('month',t.date)=DATE_PART('month',GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you CAN USE sql AND YOU actually need the previous month and not just all months summed by EventName then you could use LAG. I made the assumption that you are summing by EventName and you only want the current EventName and previous EventNAme

```
WITH Summed
AS
(
SELECT * ,
LAG(EventCount) OVER (Partition BY EventName ORDER BY trialmonth) as PrevEvent
FROM dbo.Table1 
)

    SELECT *,
    SUM(PrevEvent+EventCount) AS SummedCount

     FROM summed
     GROUP BY   Site
          ,TrialMonth
          ,EventName
          ,EventCount
          , PrevEvent
```

This will produce output like this

```
Site    TrialMonth  EventName   EventCount  PrevEvent   SummedCount
12101   2001-10-15  Actual Count    4   NULL    NULL
12101   2001-10-15  Projected Count 8   NULL    NULL
12101   2001-11-15  Actual Count    6   4   10
12101   2001-11-15  Projected Count 9   8   17
12101   2001-12-15  Actual Count    0   6   6
12101   2001-12-15  Projected Count 10  9   19
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8253f0/2